# Can I run a headless Ubuntu server with a Ryzen 5 2600 CPU but with no GPU?

Tags: graphics-card, ubuntu-server, headless

I built a headless Ubuntu server with a Ryzen 5 2600 CPU, and configured it graphically with a graphics card inserted.

When I take the graphics card out and try to boot, it does not let me SSH.

Do I need to have a graphics card to run Ubuntu Server headlessly?

Comment: It sounds like you do?  I've had systems require not just a graphics card but a dummy monitor to boot.  Some older units even required a dummy keyboard.

Comment: It doesn't require a keyboard or monitor. It boots fine without them, just not when I take out the graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

That should work, but the BIOS on many motherboards will refuse to boot if there isn't any GFX card inserted.

Or halt the boot process and give a "No GFX card, press <kbd>F1</kbd> to continue" message or something like that.

So I think your system does try to boot the first stage and then stops or pauses waiting for input. Usually it is <kbd>F1</kbd> to continue.

You'll probably have to re-insert the GFX card to check if the Bios has any options for headless operation and/or a "continue booting in case of error" possibility.

Some BIOS have a "use serial console" or IPMI console option and will only allow booting headless if that option is enabled.

And some BIOS just don't allow this at all, in which case you best throw in an old GFX card and just don't use it. (I've got a 15 year old PCI Matrox card in my Linux server just for that. It won't boot without a GFX card at all.)

Past that hurdle the system should boot and eventually enable the SSH login.

(I presume you *did* configure the SSH server and tested this before removing the GFX card. If memory serves SSH isn't enabled by default on Ubuntu desktop, but I never tried Ubuntu Server.)

Comment: I have a B450 Tomahawk MAX motherboard, and SSH does work just fine when the graphics card is inserted.

Comment: I don't see any way to disable requiring a GPU.